# TableView gets laggy with data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, lag

So I am facing a problem

A table view gets slower (responses slower to scrolling, tapping) after reloading/adding rows for a couple of times

---

So after the user logs in, the app downloads 10 *"WorldMessages"*. It is loaded into this table view.

If the user scrolls down, it calls a function which loads more 10: `loadOlderOwnWorldMessages()`

Each cell has a `tapGestureRecognizer` + `longPressGestureRecognizer`

And I have to mention that If the user reloads the tableView, then it clears the data and loads only the first 10 WorldMessages again

---

**The problem**

I don't know why, but for example, if I reload the tableView 50 times and every time I do scroll down a bit or more, then the tableView gets slow.

Maybe because of the tap/long press gesture recognizers, or constraints?

**The app looks like this:**

[image]

**Video after it gets laggy:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65NkjS-Kz3M

*(If I kill the app and I open it again, then it works smoothly again until I reload it a couple of times)*

**Code:**

// It's not the whole code, I deleted lots of lines of it that were not important (like the reload functions, and etc

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarDelegate {

    // Classes
    let handleData = HandleData()
    let handleResponses = HandleResponses()
    let worldMessagesFunctions = WorldMessagesFunctions()
    let profileFunctions = ProfileFunctions()

    // View Objects
    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!

    // Variables
    var userWorldMessages = [WorldMessage]()
    var lastContentOffsetY : CGFloat?

    var currentSelectedWorldMessageIndexPath : IndexPath?

    // Main Code
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userWorldMessages = ownWorldMessages.shared.worldMessages
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return userWorldMessages.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileWorldMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileWorldMessageCell

        let worldMessage = userWorldMessages[indexPath.row]

        cell.worldMessageData = worldMessage

        cell.messageLabel.text = worldMessage.message

        if let image = UIImage(named: "bubble") {
            let h = image.size.height / 2
            let w = image.size.width / 2
            cell.bubbleImageView.image = image
                .resizableImage(withCapInsets:
                    UIEdgeInsetsMake(h, w, h, w),
                                resizingMode: .stretch).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

            cell.bubbleImageView.tintColor = appColors.worldMessageBubble

        }

        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(worldMessage.leftTime))
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        var dateFormat = "yyyy MMM dd"
        if calendar.isDateInToday(date) {
            // Today
            dateFormat = "HH:mm"
            dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else if (calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())! < date){
            // This last 7 days
            dateFormat = "EEEE HH:mm"
        } else if (calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -12, to: Date())! < date){
            // This year
            dateFormat = "MMM dd"
        } else {
            dateFormat = "yyyy MMM dd"
        }
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        cell.timeLabel.text = strDate

        cell.commentsButton.setTitle("\(worldMessage.comments!) comments", for: .normal)
        cell.likesButton.setTitle("\(worldMessage.likes!) likes", for: .normal)

        // tapped
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bubbleTappedHandler))
        cell.bubbleButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        cell.bubbleButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        // long pressed
        let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bubbleLongPressHandler))
        longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return cell
    }
    var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height

        if indexPath.row == UserWorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.count - 1 && userWorldMessagesCanLoadMore == true {
            loadOlderOwnWorldMessages()
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if cellHeights[indexPath] != nil {
            return CGFloat(Float(cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 0.0))
        }
        else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (lastContentOffsetY != nil){
            tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: lastContentOffsetY!), animated: false)
        }
    }



    func loadOlderOwnWorldMessages(){
        profileFunctions.loadOlderOwnWorldMessages(startIndex: (userWorldMessages.count)) { response, newUserWorldMessages in
            if let response = response {
                if response.type == 1 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                        if newUserWorldMessages != nil {

                            var insertRows : [IndexPath] = []
                            var fromIndex = UserWorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.count - 1
                            for worldMessage in newUserWorldMessages! {
                                UserWorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.append(worldMessage)
                                insertRows.append(IndexPath(row: fromIndex, section: 1))
                                fromIndex += 1
                            }
                            self.userWorldMessages = UserWorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages

                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertRows, with: .automatic)
                            self.tableView.endUpdates()


                        }

                        })
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                        self.handleResponses.displayError(title: response.title, message: response.message)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func bubbleTappedHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, should: Bool) {
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            if indexPath == currentSelectedWorldMessageIndexPath {
                // it was already selected, so deselect it

                deselectCurrentSelectedWorldMessage()
            } else {
                // select new one, deselect old one if was selected

                if (currentSelectedWorldMessageIndexPath != nil){
                    deselectCurrentSelectedWorldMessage()
                }

                selectWorldMessage(indexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
    func selectWorldMessage(indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        currentSelectedWorldMessageIndexPath = indexPath

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProfileWorldMessageCell {

            // Change some constraints
            cell.messageLabelTopConstraint.constant = 14
            cell.messageLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 14
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    @objc func deselectCurrentSelectedWorldMessage(){
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
        if (currentSelectedWorldMessageIndexPath == nil){
            return
        }
        let indexPath = currentSelectedWorldMessageIndexPath!

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProfileWorldMessageCell {

            // Change back some constraints
            cell.messageLabelTopConstraint.constant = 10
            cell.messageLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 10
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            }, completion: nil)
        }

        currentSelectedWorldMessageIndexPath = nil
    }

    @objc func bubbleLongPressHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer, should: Bool) {
        // Show options like copy, delete etc.
    }



}
```

Comment: Without going through all the code you posted, I'd consider it's *not* the `UITableView` that's the cause, but the `[WorldMessages]` array behind it. Table views are built *for* performance by caching and reusing their displayed cells. I see you are doing some array inserts, table view cell inserts, and a few other things in `loadOlderOwnWorldMessages` - and explicitly doing this on the main queue. (1) Can you offload retrieving these messages to another thread? (2) Why are you inserting cells? Could you just update the array, call `reloadData`, and then set the top cell to what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couple of things that are *very* wrong with your `cellForRow` function:

- the cells are reused, and you are ignoring that fact. You are creating new instances of gesture recognizers each time `cellForRow` is called, and when cell is reused you are adding yet another one. That means that if your cell had been reused for 50th time, it will have 50 gesture recognizers added. You should create your gesture recognizers only once
- You create a `DateFormatter` and set its `dateFormat` property each time, and that is actually really expensive process. Instead you should have a static instance of formatter for each date format

Comment: oh silly me, yes I did not realise that I was doing this wrong.. I was not familiar with the gestureRecognisers and found a tutorial online (which turns out to be the problem)